# running virtualenv nothing happen

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv

I'm on a **Windows** machine, using **python 2.7.11**.
I've installed virtualenv using pip

`pip install virtualenv`

when I run `C:\Users\MyFolder>virtualenv`  from command line, seems that nothing is happening. The cursor still blinking like it was working and in fact the process is still running, but just nothing happens.

I've tried to reinstall virtualenv and python but the problem still remains.
I also tried to import virtualenv from python and no problem of importing is reported.

Someone has had similar issues?

Comment: Does `virtualen --help` do anything?

Comment: No, nothing happens.. :S

Comment: Have you specified the directory to create the virtual environment in? "virtualenv venv"

Comment: Yes of course, but nothing...